# SQL - commit only if dataset changes

Tags: sql, commit

I`m pulling some data from a website and would like to write it into an sql-db.

```
14:30 Data_1
14:31 Data_1
14:32 Data_1
14:33 Data_2
```

Most of the time the data is static so I only commit if the data changes.

```
14:30 Data_1
14:33 Data_2
```

The problem with this is that I do miss the last timestamp before the dataset changed:

```
14:30 Data_1
14:32 Data_1
14:33 Data_2
```

Is there an elegant way to do this in sql?

Right now I use the following code:

```
sql = """
INSERT INTO c2g (time, data1, data2, lat, lon, city, geom)
SELECT %(time)s, %(data1)s, %(data2)s, %(lat)s, %(lon)s, %(city)s, st_setsrid(st_makepoint( %(lon)s, %(lat)s), 4326)
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM c2g WHERE data1= %(data1)s AND lat = %(lat)s AND lon = %(lon)s AND data2= %(data2)s);
"""
```

It works fine but the result is just not exactly what I need :(

Comment: Can you provide the code you are currently using?

Comment: When you check whether the data has changed, you need to update the last time stamp on the record.  I would include two timestamps, the first and the last.

Comment: @mellamokb sure! just added the code